# What type of property should I use if it's supposed to contain formatted text, images, links, etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a "Page" class that will have a "Content" property - this will be located on a web form and the user should be able to format the text, insert pictures, attachments, etc.  What type of Property should this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is a good candidate for your property type.

Comment: For a Web-Only ViewModel yes.. for a DB entity.. no.

Comment: This is true, but the OP didn't mention that the `Page` class is a DB entity, unless I misunderstood the question.